# Can I create notifications to go out when a child ticket is closed in ADO?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have child tickets in each ADO campaign. Each child ticket is assigned to a different owner to complete. Most of the time the work is done in waterfall model so when the first child ticket task is complete, I'd like it to trigger a notification so that the person in charge of the next child ticket is notified so they can start.

I can't find any documentation on this.